# How to change the window 445 port

Tags: window, virtualbox, samba, nat

my **host** OS is **window7**;
my **guest** OS is **centos7** is runing on  **virtualbox**;
i hope **share centos7's files** for **window7** via **samba server**;
the samba server is runing in the centos7;

when centos7 connect network with "**Bridged networking**" or "**Host-only networking**" ;
Assuming that  the centos7 IP is **10.254.254.254**;
i can Configuring a-network-driver for window7,like "**\\10.254.254.254\www**",it is **working**;

now,i only want to use  "**Network Address Translation Service (experimental)**" for the centos7; but **i still want to share centos7's files for window7 via "samba server"**;

i can Configuring port forwarding with NAT,like that:

```
hostIP:port <= guestIP:port
0.0.0.0:80 <= 10.254.254.2:80  
127.0.0.2:22 <= 10.254.254.2:22
```

now i can visit my web : http://192.168.1.8 or http://127.0.0.2;
and connect the ssh server: 127.0.0.2:22 
**it working;**

but,if i Configuring the smb port forwarding with NAT,like:

```
127.0.0.2:445 <= 10.254.254.2:445   (it not working)  
127.0.0.2:139 <= 10.254.254.2:139  (it working)
```

**i know i can not re-bind the 445 port for "centos's" smb server;**

so, i can not share file via "\\127.0.0.2\www"; 
then,i google,some one say:"window smb server and client port is 445"; 
now i think:"can i change the window's port of 445 to anyother number,4450?5555?",if it can,i can Configuring the smb port forwarding with NAT,like:

```
127.0.0.2:4450 <= 10.254.254.2:445  
127.0.0.2:1390 <= 10.254.254.2:139
```

i had try :

1. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters

   ```
   Value Name: SmbDeviceEnabled
   Type: REG_DWORD
   Value Data: 0
   ```

   and then restart window7, but the "netstat -p TCP -noba" still show me:

   ```
   [svchost.exe] TCP    0.0.0.0:445
   ```
2. try change port to 5555,and restart,but fail,the port still show me 445

   > Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
   >    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters\Smb] 
   >   "SessionPort"=dword:0000022b
   >   "DatagramPort"=dword:0000022b

any idea ?
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this problem cannot be solved;
I am using the following solutions now:

1 rebuid my nginx service from nginx-source,to add webDAV mod;
2 share centos7's files via nginx-webDAV service;

why?
because i found:

when i use "host-only" and "NAT"  for centos,They are all the LAN IP address ;

when the guest os's ip setting like that:
the interface of "host-only":

```
 IPDDR=10.254.254.254, and my host os don't sharing my WIFI for it,  
so it can't connect to WAN,   
becuase i only want it share me centos's files ;
```

the interface of "NAT" :

```
 ipddr=10.0.0.2,it can connect to WAN,  
for the other services,like:ssh/web/mysql, and so on;
```

then ssh/web/mysql don't know connect to which GATEWAY.

maybe i can write some "route" to fix it,but it is a big bad thing;